# Issue with bcc headers sending email

Tags: php

I have this code which is supposed to permit me to send an email to multiple addresses, but, the issue is, it doesn't send them to multiple Bcc...

Here is the code:

```
$emailbcc=$_POST['emailbcc'];
$sub=$_POST['subject'];
$msg=$_POST['message'];
$emailbcc1= implode("," , $emailbcc);
if($emailbcc!=''){

// multiple recipients
$to = 'address';

// subject
$subject = $sub;

// message
$message = $msg;

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'From: Up!<address>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: '.$emailbcc1.'' . "\r\n";


// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

`$emailbcc1` are some e-mails, i get them using checkboxes...
What is wrong with this?
Thanks..

Comment: just a friendly note - you may want to use mail components / plugins that already exist instead... they solve most common problems with different e-mail clients, encodings etc. (see [PHPMailer](https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/) or [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make them emails:

```
$emailbcc1 = implode(">, <" , $emailbcc);
$emailbcc1 = '<'.$emailbcc1.'>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that these mail addresses are seperated with a `,`!

For example, when you have an array with addresses:

```
$addresses = array('example1@example.com', 'example2@example.com');
```

You can set the header in this way:

```
$headers .= 'BCC: ' + implode(',', $addresses) + '\r\n';
```